# Toast Message not showing on Nexus 6 during incoming call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, toast, incoming-call

I have an app that is gonna show the contact details of the incoming phone number from a DB. The information is displayed as a toast message. The problem I have is: If my screen is on when I get the call the toast message is seen but if my screen is off then when the call comes the toast message is not displayed. Weirdest part is I tested this on samsung galaxy's and HTC's, there it is working as expected even when screen is off. I am seeing the issue only on my nexus 6. So I am guessing it has something to do with Lollipop's incoming call screen. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check whether notifications are enabled for the apps.Here is the issue which is related to this https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35013

To turn notifications on 
Go to Settings -> Apps -> App Name ->  "Show Notifications"